# CSS3 transform: translate on hover, with transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

This should be really simple.

I have a bunch of anchors in my HTML, like so:

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
```

And in CSS I placed a hover effect to do a `translate: transform();`

```
a {
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

a:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -5px);
}
```

Now, this should make the anchors move up 5 pixels when you hover them. And they do, but they snap down immediately, even though the mouse still hovers. Anyone else encountered this behavior and found a solution? I'd like the effect to stay active **while** mouse hovers.
Codepen link: http://codepen.io/BrianEmilius/pen/NqoLQo

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because, on the transform, you aren't hovering over the *exact* link anymore.

If you make the links `display:inline-block` you might get better results.

```css
a {
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -5px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Also, don't forget about vendor specific. Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waNYKN

Comment: Yup, this did it! Thought it would be a simple solution :) @JoshSalazar yeah codepen doesn'tneed the vendor prefixes in most cases, but they're in my project code.

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to be because of the hit area. If you look at the second snippet in the answer that I linked you would see that the same behavior happens even when you do `body:hover`. It seems more to do with the accelerated rendering process. The solution however is still the same :)

Comment: @Harry Yeah...I see you found the right dupe target. I've removed that part.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because by default `a` elements have an `inline` display and the `translate` property can only properly affect block-level elements.

To fix this, simply give your `a` elements a `display` property set to `inline-block`:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqoOqm).